# How do I run a web app in my WordPress theme without the "wp-content/theme/.../webapp" in URL?

Tags: customization, themes, url-rewriting

hope everyone's doing great.

I have a web application that's pretty much a folder containing an index.html and some javascript stuff. I  placed this folder in my theme folder.

It works perfectly when I try to run it like: domain/wp-content/themes/theme-name/webapp/

Here's the issue.
**I want to hide the "domain/wp-content/themes/theme-name".**

e.g. A normal page looks like this: "domain/page-name".
I want the web app to look like this: "domain/webapp".

Is there any way I could go about doing this? I do not wish to touch any code in the webapp if possible, since it's from a third party.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A simple way would be creating a page template file for your app's frontend.

Comment: Can't you just put the folder in the root web directory?